# Erase pointer in two maps

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have two maps. The keys of the two maps are the same. The mapped-value of the second one is a pointer, which points to the mapped-value of the first one. When I erase the element in the first map, the pointer in the second map does not vanish automatically. I should first erase the second map and then erase the first one.

```
// two maps
map<int, int> a;
map<int, int*> pt_a;

int N = 5;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    a.insert({ i,2 * i });
    pt_a.insert({ i,&(a[i]) });
}

// erase the first element of a
a.erase(a.begin());

// after erase
for (auto& i : a) cout << i.first << " " << &(i.second) << endl;
cout << endl;

for (auto& i : pt_a) cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;
```

1. Is there anything in C++ can simplify this code? If the element in the first map is erased, the corresponding one in the second map is also erased automatically.
2. If I erase the element in the second map, the memory of pointer is free or not? Should I use `std::share_ptr` in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use a single map? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: In the code you have posted you are not allocating any memory, so you shouldn't be worrying about whether it's free or not.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I made a simplification for my problem. Actually in my code, the first map is large and the second one is very small which point to only a part of the first one.

Comment: *Is there anything in C++ can simplify this code* -- Change your design.  Informing other entities that "something has happened, so do something" can be implemented using the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: You could solve your problem by not having any overlap between the maps. Means two lookups to find something which is in the smaller map, but it would also mean you don't have the issue of synchronizing the maps.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see. I will have to make two lookups for the maps.

Comment: @john Yes, I will have to make two lookups for the maps. Thanks!